# replacing li background image

Tags: css, list, menu, selecteditem

I have a menu which I'm mimicking an old tape deck. Each list item has a background image of a button. When an item is selected a new background image shows the button in the down position. however, I can still see the other image underneath. How can I have the original image replaced by the selected image. Please see http://www.saintalvia.com to see what I  mean.

Thanks!

```
#access a { 
font-family:Roboto;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:12px;
padding: 0 9px 2px 9px;
-moz-border-radius:0 0 0 0 !important;
-webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
border-radius:0 !important;
border-radius:0 !important;
}

#access .menu-header li,
div.menu li {
margin-top:0px;
height:80px;
}

#access ul li {
margin-right:8px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom;
background-image:url(http://www.saintalvia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/newButton.png);
}
#access ul li.current_page_item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-item > a,
#access li.selected > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-parent > a,
#access ul li.current_page_item > a:hover,
#access ul li.current-menu-item > a:hover {
height:80px;
background-color:transparent;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom;
background-image:url(http://www.saintalvia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/buttonDownNew.png)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the "up" image set on the `<li>` and the down set on `<a>`.  Set the down on the current `<li>` instead of the `<a>`

To improve this I would also combine the up and down versions of the button into one image to create what is called a CSS sprite.  Then when you want to shift the button to the down position all you need to do is tweak the `background-position`.

Comment: thank you works great now! Yes  you are right. the sprite would be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You've got one image on the `a` tag and one on the `li` tag, so when the page goes to the link you click on you should change the image on the same tag which it was on before, not add it on top on another tag. Either tag should work, you just need to pick one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `li` has the background of the up button and the `li a` has the down button background.